# I am using Xcode10.1, and it is crashing unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, xcode10.1

Tried cleaning caches and other method mentioned on forum to resolve this but dint worked. If I open new project it works, but that also crashes after 3-4 days.How this can be resolved
[![ ][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your screen shot does not show the stack trace of the crashed main thread. Maybe one can find valuable information there.

Comment: @ReinhardMännerupdated the new screenshot.

Comment: The stack trace shows that an Xcode internal software package, IDE, hit an assertion that failed. This seems to be an Xcode bug, and a report has been sent to Apple automatically. If the usual things (clearing the project, deleting the derived data, restart of Xcode und rebooting the Mac) do not help, I also suggest to upgrade to Xcode 11.

Answer (score 0):

Delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData by running this command in terminal:

```
rm -r ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData
```

If that doesnt work, At this point and with given info, all I could recommend to delete and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for a quick reply, I tried running command and did reinstalled Xcode also, nothing worked.

Comment: if you are using pods than go to Workspace right click > show package content > delete xcuserdata foler go back same thing again for xcodeproj and again do it for workspace. second option is to update your xcode to 10.2